# Airflow 2.0: Encapsulating DAG in class using Taskflow API

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

I have pipelines where the mechanics are always the same, a sequence of two tasks.
So I try to abstract the construction of it through a parent abstract class (using TaskFlow API):

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from datetime import datetime

def AbstractDag(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def task_1(self):
        """task 1"""

    @abstractmethod
    def task_2(self, data):
        """task 2"""

    def dag_wrapper(self):
        @dag(schedule_interval=None, start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1))
        def dag():
            @task(task_id='task_1')
            def task_1():
                return self.task_1()

            @task(task_id='task_2')
            def task_2(data):
                return self.task_2(data)

            task_2(task_1())

        return dag
```

But when I try to inherit this class, I can't see my dag in the interface:

```py
class MyCustomDag(AbstractDag):
    def task_1(self):
        return 2

    @abstractmethod
    def task_2(self, data):
        print(data)


custom_dag = MyCustomDag()
dag_object = custom_dag.dag_wrapper()
```

Do you have any idea how to do this? or better ideas to abstract this?

Thanks a lot!
Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get your example DAG to render in the UI with just a couple small tweaks:

- The `MyCustomDag.task_2` method doesn't need to be decorated as an `abstractmethod`.
- Using `dag()` as the wrapped DAG object function name has its issues since it's also a decorator name.
- In the `AbstractDag.dag_wrapper` method you do need to call the `@dag`-decorated function.

Here is the code I used:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from datetime import datetime

class AbstractDag(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def task_1(self):
        """task 1"""

    @abstractmethod
    def task_2(self, data):
        """task 2"""

    def dag_wrapper(self):
        @dag(schedule_interval=None, start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1))
        def _dag():
            @task(task_id='task_1')
            def task_1():
                return self.task_1()

            @task(task_id='task_2')
            def task_2(data):
                return self.task_2(data)

            task_2(task_1())

        return _dag()


class MyCustomDag(AbstractDag):
    def task_1(self):
        return 2

    def task_2(self, data):
        print(data)


custom_dag = MyCustomDag()
dag_object = custom_dag.dag_wrapper()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting the following from the [Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#loading-dags) :

> When searching for DAGs inside the DAG_FOLDER, Airflow only considers Python files that contain the strings airflow and dag (case-insensitively) as an optimization.
>
> To consider all Python files instead, disable the
> DAG_DISCOVERY_SAFE_MODE configuration flag.

If you're inheriting from `AbstractDag` in a different file, make sure `airflow` and `dag` are in that file. You can simply add a comment with those words.